# Construct JSON payload in same order Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I am trying to construct a `JSON` to make a `POST` call. I want my `JSON` to be in the same order I constructed my params but if I print it the order is different.

```
let params = ["type": "UserVal","Name": "name", "Domain": "local","IsValid": true,"Search": true] as [String : Any]
print ("The parameters is",params)
if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options:[]) {
if let content = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
   print("The content is",content)
}
```

My expected `JSON` is:

```
{  
"type":"UserVal",
"Name":"name",
"Domain":"local",
"IsValid":true,
"Search":true
}
```

But the `JSON` I am getting is:

```
{  
"IsValid":true,
"type":"UserVal",
"Name":"name",
"Search":true,
"Domain":"local",
}
```

Please let me know how to construct JSON without changing the oder.

Comment: Because the Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Tested & working fine already

Comment: Why does it matter if the values are in a particular order? It should't matter.

Comment: I am not getting the response if I change the order. I tested my service in postman too. I am not sure what the backend is verifying. But it is expecting type to be the first parameter.

Comment: You seems to have a lot of knowledge for iOS, why asking such weird question? If you want to keep the order, dont use `JSONSerialization `, but directly decode the raw data into string